# Entity class for scenario using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, entity, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

**Scenario**

1. Fetch product details of specific order.
2. Fetch order details of specific product.

**SQL server tables**

1. Table_Orders
2. Table_OrderDetails
3. Table_Products

**Entity classes**

1. Model_orders

   ```
   @Entity
   @Table(name="Tbl_Orders")
   public class Order
   {
       public Order() {
       }

       @Id
       @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
       @Column(name="Order_ID")
       private Long orderId;

       @Column(name="OrderNo")
       private String orderNumber;

       @Column(name="OrderDate")
       private Date orderDate;

       @ManyToOne()
       @JoinColumn(name="User_ID")
       private Customer customerOrder;



       public Long getOrderId() {
           return orderId;
       }

       public void setOrderId(Long orderId) {
           this.orderId = orderId;
       }

       public String getOrderNumber() {
           return orderNumber;
       }

       public void setOrderNumber(String orderNumber) {
           this.orderNumber = orderNumber;
       }

       public Date getOrderDate() {
           return orderDate;
       }

       public void setOrderDate(Date orderDate) {
           this.orderDate = orderDate;
       }

       public Customer getCustomerOrder() {
           return customerOrder;
       }

       public void setCustomerOrder(Customer customerOrder) {
           this.customerOrder = customerOrder;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Model_OrderDetails

   ```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "Tbl_OrderDetails")
   public class OrderDetail {

       public OrderDetail() {
           super();
       }

       @Id
       @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
       @Column(name = "OrderDetail_ID")
       private Long orderDetailsId;

       @ManyToOne
       @JoinColumn(name = "Order_ID")
       private Order orderId;

       @ManyToOne
       @JoinColumn(name = "Product_ID")
       private ProductMaster product;


       public Long getOrderDetailsId() {
           return orderDetailsId;
       }

       public void setOrderDetailsId(Long orderDetailsId) {
           this.orderDetailsId = orderDetailsId;
       }

       public Order getOrderId() {
           return orderId;
       }

       public void setOrderId(Order orderId) {
           this.orderId = orderId;
       }



       public ProductMaster getProduct() {
           return product;
       }

       public void setProduct(ProductMaster product) {
           this.product = product;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Model_Products

   ```
   @Entity
   @Table (name = "Tbl_Products")
   public class ProductMaster
   {
       public Products() {
       }

       @Id
       @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
       @Column (name = "Product_ID")
       @Field(index= Index.YES, analyze= Analyze.YES, store= Store.YES)
       private Long productId;

       @Column (name = "Product_Code")
       private String productCode;

       @Column (name = "Product_Name")
       @Field(index= Index.YES, analyze= Analyze.YES, store= Store.YES  ,analyzer=@Analyzer(definition = "customanalyzer"))
       private String productName;



       public Long getProductId() {
           return productId;
       }

       public void setProductId(Long productId) {
           this.productId = productId;
       }


       public String getProductCode() {
           return productCode;
       }

       public void setProductCode(String productCode) {
           this.productCode = productCode;
       }

       public String getProductName() {
           return productName;
       }

       public void setProductName(String productName) {
           this.productName = productName;
       }
   }
   ```

**Problem description**

In this entity classes i used many to one mapping in all three classes. My scenario mentioned above is many to many. One order can have multiple products, at the same time one product is placed in many orders.

My problem is using order id i need to get all product details. Similarly using product id i need to get all order details. I think to use one to many mapping in order detail entity class but i don't know how to map it. Is that is the right way?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the purpose of Table_OrderDetails is just to create a mapping between Order_ID and Product_ID. So this should not be created as a separated 'Entity'. Instead Hibernates @ManyToMany should be used.

Order.java

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name="Tbl_Orders")
public class Order
{
    public Order() {
    }
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="Order_ID")
    private Long orderId;

    @Column(name="OrderNo")
    private String orderNumber;

    @Column(name="OrderDate")
    private Date orderDate;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "Tbl_OrderDetails",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "Order_ID"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "Product_ID"))
    private List<ProductMaster> productMasters = new ArrayList<>();

    public Long getOrderId() {
        return orderId;
    }

    public void setOrderId(Long orderId) {
        this.orderId = orderId;
    }

    public String getOrderNumber() {
        return orderNumber;
    }

    public void setOrderNumber(String orderNumber) {
        this.orderNumber = orderNumber;
    }

    public Date getOrderDate() {
        return orderDate;
    }

    public void setOrderDate(Date orderDate) {
        this.orderDate = orderDate;
    }

    public List<ProductMaster> getProductMasters() {
        return productMasters;
    }

    public void setProductMasters(List<ProductMaster> productMasters) {
        this.productMasters = productMasters;
    }
}
```

ProductMaster.java

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Tbl_Products")
public class ProductMaster
{
    public ProductMaster() {
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column (name = "Product_ID")
    private Long productId;

    @Column (name = "Product_Code")
    private String productCode;

    @Column (name = "Product_Name")
    private String productName;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "productMasters")
    private List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();

    public Long getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(Long productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }


    public String getProductCode() {
        return productCode;
    }

    public void setProductCode(String productCode) {
        this.productCode = productCode;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public List<Order> getOrders() {
        return orders;
    }

    public void setOrders(List<Order> orders) {
        this.orders = orders;
    }
}
```

This will automatically create a third table 'Tbl_OrderDetails' with both the Id columns. 
And you will be able to get all orders for one product, and all products in one order.

Comment: When i try this i have an error :org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: rentd.model.Order.ordersDetail, could not initialize proxy - no Session

Comment: Am i need to delete order detail entity class r i need to do any change in order detail??

Comment: OrderDetail entity class is not needed. Hibernate will automatically create the TBL_ORDER_DETAILS table. Regarding the LazyInitializationException, try adding `fetch = FetchType.EAGER`  to both the @ManyToMany annotations

Comment: I added  fetch = FetchType.EAGER to both , it throws error [GET http://localhost:8080/RentdIn/GetAllRentdUser?isSupername=admin net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING 200 (OK)]  in browser console and stack overflow error in eclipse console.

Comment: Garima , Consider this , I have user table ,department table and mapping table , where one user can be part of many department & one department have many user is the concept . My problem is i have 2 entity class for department & user respectively . I need to do following operations one by one  1) register user , 2) register department , 3) view all registered departments ,4) view all registered users ,5) select particular user and view what are all the departments he  registered and 6)  select  particular  department and view who are all the user in that department .

Comment: Now come to the problem, while i try to get all user list , the entity many to many annotation in user class throw the error . I really need a clarification how to do the operation and how my entity classes could be .

Answer (score 0):

Fetch product details of specific order.

Create a bidirectional mapping of Order to OrderDetail.

```
Into Order:
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "orderId", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Collection<OrderDetail> ordersDetail;
```

Fetch order details of specific product.

Create a bidirectional mapping of ProductMaster to OrderDetail.

```
Into ProductMaster:
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "product", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Collection<OrderDetail> ordersDetail;
```

Comment: When i try this also i  have same  error :org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: rentd.model.Order.ordersDetail, could not initialize proxy - no Session

Comment: Am i need to delete order detail entity class r i need to do any change in order detail??